# Associative array values to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have javascript associative array following

```
var list = {};
list['a'] = 'one';
list['b'] = 'two';
list['c'] = 'two';
```

By jquery ajax, I want pass only values of list array in json format.

```
{"list":["one","two","two"]}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Side note: it's not an associative array, it's an object.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to extract values:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        list: $.map(list, function(val) { return val; })
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = {};
list['a'] = 'one';
list['b'] = 'two';
list['c'] = 'two';

var newObj = {
    "list": []
};

for (key in list) {
    newObj.list.push(list[key]);
}

alert(JSON.stringify(newObj));​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/rS7j6/)

Answer (score 0):

There are no associative *arrays* in javascript, only objects whose properties have no order. That means if you wanted to build an array of them, you'd need to sort the properties first:

```
var list = {a:'one', b:'two', c:'two'};

var result = {list:[]},
    keys = [];
for (var key in list)
    keys.push(key);
keys.sort();
for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
    result.list[i] = list[keys[i]];
return JSON.stringify(result);
```

Or the same thing with some helper functions, which may not be supported natively by all browsers:

```
return {list: Object.keys(list).sort().map(function(key) { return list[key]; })};
```